# Dual control of relay

Tags: diodes, relay, gpio

I have one relay and two power sources. The first is a cellphone charger and the second is the HIGH signal from a GPIO on a Raspberry Pi.

- If any one of them supplies power the relay is on.
- If both supplies power the relay is on.
- If the cellphone charger is disconnected and the GPIO is LOW, the relay is off.

I have tried to isolate the schematics in the image below.

[image]

Will this work? Do I need the 2 diodes? Why/why not?

The following is a complete schema of my assassin solution.
As you can see there is a [Adafruit Powerboost 1000c](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2465). The EN pin is relevant to this question.

According to documentation:

> EN - this is the 'enable' pin. By default it is pulled 'high' to VS. To turn off the booster, connect this pin to ground. The switch can be as small as you like, it is just a signal. Contrast this to an inline power switch which would have to be able to handle up to 2 A of current! When the chip is disabled the output is completely disconnected from the input.

The pink parts are the parts relevant to this question.
The photo on the far right is a little box that controls the radiators in my cabin. Just added it so you get the full picture.

[image]

Comment: What is R2 doing? What current does your relay need? What current can your sources supply? I'm guessing you need to eliminate R2 and boost the current from that GPIO.

Comment: Do you really need a relay here? Why can't you just control the EN pin directly?

Comment: Nobody is going to call you any names!

Comment: GPIO is not a power source ... it is a signal source

Comment: @BrianDrummond: Since I'm a noob I thought I needed R2 to not draw to much current from the GPIO. Based on your comment I guess I was wrong. Good to know. The GPIO supply 3v3 or 3v, not sure about the current. The cellphone charger 5v and 1amp. I haven't checked the required current on any of my relays in a while. In the photo I use 2 DIL relays. They work with out a boost. I just have to check the other I have. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @user253751. So you suggest going strait from the GPIO and strait from the cellphone charger? How does this connect the EN pin to ground when GPIO is low and cellphone charger is disconnected? Thanks for commenting.

Comment: @jsotola. I'm fully aware that is is a signal source. It is wrong of me to call it power source. I used the term power instead of signal since I in this case it will be used to control a relay. Thank you for correcting me.

Comment: @BeachBumBob well you'd output low which is the same thing as connecting to ground. And when you don't want it to go low you set it to input mode and it doesn't pull high or low. And for the cellphone charger you use a transistor as a switch.

Comment: You still need to know if the relay will work from the GPIO. Find out its current requirement and the current the GPIO can supply. Their datasheets can tell you that.

Comment: @BrianDrummond It's hard to find what one single pin can provide but all (40 of them) should be able to supply 50mA. Have to check the relays and do some tests on a breadboard.

Comment: @user253751 I'll try the direct GPIO and cellphone charger w. transistor on a breadboard. Thanks.

Comment: Beware that the Pi uses 3.3V GPIO. Applying 5V to the Pi's GPIO pin may damage it. So you might also need a transistor with the GPIO. I don't know what voltage the EN pin has when you don't pull it to ground.

Answer (score 0):

For relay controls, you generally associate ORs with parallel wiring and ANDS with series wiring.  So can you simply wire the GPIO and the USB power supply in parallel to the relay coil?

Probably not.  They are separate voltage sources and mingling them will have unpredictable unintended results.  With relay controls, a simple answer is to add interposing relays:

- The USB power supply to the coil of one interposing relay
- The GPIO to the coil of another interposing relay
- The contacts of the two interposing relays in parallel between a power source and the control relay coil

Now you can select the interposing relay for the USB power with a coil suitable for USB power, and the interposing relay for the GPIO with a coil suitable for logic-level power, likely a solid state relay, and it may require a power supply separate from the contacts and coil.

The NO contacts of the control relay will then close when either the USB power supply is on **OR** the GPIO is high.

You'll need a power supply suitable for the coil of the control relay, and the **contacts** of the interposing relays must be rated so they're compatible with the **coil** of the control relay and that power supply.

This is a bit convoluted, which is typical with relay controls.  It may be better to achieve the control by wiring the power supply to another GPIO and using the RPi's logic to do the OR, and switch another GPIO that operates the coil of the control relay.  But there is a trade-off, you have to have access to the RPi's code, the ability to modify and maintain that code, and have the IOs available to do what you need to do.